# knockout, checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have table, and I want check/uncheckcheck box not only by clicking on checkbox, but on clicking on anywere in row too.
Code is here: [source](http://jsfiddle.net/M8KFd/563/)
But code works well only when I click on row. When I click on checkbox, logic works well but not checkbox.
PS. Value in array `selectedAnimals` should be animal object, not only ID or Name

PS2. With jQuery

```
   $("table").on("click", "tbody tr", function(e){
       ko.dataFor(this).isSelected(!ko.dataFor(this).isSelected())
    })
```

all working well, but I want do it witout jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening when you check the checkbox:

- Item gets checked & added to the array (correct).
- The `add` function is called due to event bubbling (the checkbox is in the `TR`, which has the click function added).
- This function flips the checkbox again, which will cause it to be removed from the list and unchecks it.

You can't prevent the event bubbling when using the `checked:` binding, so the best way to do this is remove the `add` function from the whole `TR` and move it to it's own `TD`.

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8KFd/577/).

Comment: yep, it's works, but if I have more then one column <td>, then I must set data-bind="click... for-each?

Comment: Sadly, yes. You can look into [binding without a container element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_3_using_foreach_without_a_container_element) to get DRY code, but you'll get more nested arrays.